# Parse streaming JSON in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json

I am using JSON-RPC over TCP, the problem is that I could not find any JSON parse capable of parsing multiple JSON objects correctly, and it would be relatively hard to split it, since there is no delimiter used.

Anyone knows a way how I could handle i.e. this:

`{"foo":false, "bar: true, "baz": "cool"}{"ba`

Somehow I need to split it so I end up just with the first, complete JSON object. The remaining string needs to stay in buffer until I have enough data to parse it properly.

Comment: Well, it's not JSON, it's multiple JSON streams concatenated.  I suspect that you're losing some sort of separator in the data stream.

Comment: If you're totally not worried about CPU usage, you can try to parse it after each character received in your TCP stream. Other than that, you'll have to use a separator or something like that.

Comment: @HotLicks Unfortunately I am not, there is no delimiter, [the documentation](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=JSON-RPC_API#TCP) is clear on that.

Comment: You would expect something like: [{"foo":false, "bar": true, "baz": "cool"},{"ba  - An array, with a first element that is a dictionary that we could have read completely, and a second element that is a dictionary but not even the first key is known yet. It's tricky. And there's the problem that incorrect JSON should not be partially interpreted, so whatever you do you must be able to undo if later stuff contains errors.

Comment: @BrunoWerminghoff This would be _very_ inefficient, unfortunately I can't change the JSON I receive from the server, this is out of my control. (It is [generated by XBMC](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=JSON-RPC_API#TCP))

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes thats right, despite that it isn't an array but just JSON objects one after another, without delimiter, depending how fast I make requests/get reponses. It seems the guys that implemented it in XBMC did not thought a delimiter would be useful.

Comment: @ePirat yeah, I know it would be insanely inefficient, that why I mentioned you can't be worried about CPU usage while using that approach :)

Comment: The only practical approach is to use a JSON parser that stops at the end of a JSON string and tells you where the next character is (or leaves itself ready to read the next character).  A pretty dumb design.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@ePirat, if someone just concatenates multiple JSON dictionaries without delimiters, they should be shot.

For parsing: JSONSerialization parses NSData which could come in any encoding. Fortunately, if you have multiple JSON dictionaries concatenated, they are quite easy to take apart. All you need is looking at the bytes and check for the characters \ " { and }.

If you find a { then increase the counter for "open brackets". 
If you find a } then decrease the counter for "open brackets". If the counter is at zero, you've found the end of a dictionary.

If you find a ", then repeatedly look at the next character. If the next character is a " then skip it and go to the normal processing (you've found the end of a string). If the next character is a \ then skip that character and the following character. If the next character is anything else, skip it.

If you reach the end of the data, then your JSON data is incomplete. You could remember which state you were in (count of open brackets, whether you are parsing a string, and if parsing a string whether you just encountered a backlash character) and continue right where you left off.

No need to convert the NSData to a string until you've separated it into dictionaries. If you suspect that you might be given UTF-16 or UTF-32, check whether bytes 0, 1, 2 or 1, 2, 3 are zero (UTF-32), then check whether bytes 0 and 2 or 1 and 3 are zero (UTF-16). But in that case, if the server sends non-standard JSON in UTF-16 or UTF-32, change "the person responsible should be shot" to "the person responsible must be shot".

Comment: "They should be shot" is a rather radical position considering that there is an unambiguous interpretation of the data.

Comment: "Concatenated JSON" is supported by other JSON parsers.

Answer (score 1):

[XBMC's JSON-RPC doc](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=JSON-RPC_API#TCP) does give a hint:

> As such, your client needs to be able to deal with this, **eg. by counting and matching curly braces ({})**.

**Update**: As [Jody Hagins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/508595/jody-hagins) pointed out, beware of curly braces inside JSON strings when using this approach.

Another possible and probably much better solution would be using a streaming JSON parser like [yajl](http://lloyd.github.io/yajl/) (or its Objective-C wrapper [yajl-objc](https://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc)). You can feed the parser with data until it says the current object is done and then restart parsing.

Comment: Make sure you ignore curly braces contained inside quotes.

Comment: @JodyHagins Thanks for the hint. I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Using the streaming parser was no solution since there is no way to restart the parser with the remaining data.

Comment: @ePirat You could feed the parser in chunks until the next `]` or `}`, e.g. with a packet containing `{"foo":{"bar":"baz"},"bar":"baz"}{"foo":`, you feed `{"foo":{"bar":"baz"}`, then `,"bar":"baz"}`. At this point, the parser would say the object completed and then you would have `{"foo":` left which you can feed into the restarted parser

Comment: yajl can surely be used for this. You can figure out how much was consumed after a successful parse and re-use the rest of it for the next parse operation. (see doc for : yajl_get_bytes_consumed)